# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected & ERROR: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, syntax-error, aggregate-functions

I am receiving the titled to error messages(first in sqldeveloper and second in sqlplus)

The following is my code for the following task:

For each customers we have in the customers table, display the customer id and last name. If the customer has any orders last year display the average amount due for those orders and the highest amount due for those orders. Display the string ' no orders' if there are no orders. Order by the customer id.

```
Select 
DISTINCT cust_id As CustID, cust_name_last AS "CustName",
NVL( to_char( AVG( order_price * quantity )),'9999.99'),'no orders') AS
"AverageAmntDue",
NVL( to_char( MAX( order_price * quantity ),'9999.99'),' no orders') AS   
"HighestAmntDue"
From bk_customers
LEFT JOIN bk_order_headers using (cust_id)
LEFT JOIN bk_order_details using (order_id)
Where TO_CHAR (order_date, 'YYYY’) = 2014
Group by cust_id, cust_name_last
Order by cust_id;
```

EDIT:

(The following was an attempted edit on my answer, but it should have gone here.)
what the task ask for is .....
For each customers we have in the customers table, display the customer id and last name. If 
the customer has any orders last year display the average amount due for those orders and the 
highest amount due for those orders. Display the string ' no orders' if there are no orders. Order 
by the customer id

What I am being told by my instructor that I should be looking at is a way to You need to think about how to say what you want returned:
You want customer with _____order date test___
and customers with ___ no orders at all test ____.

What I have written does not return customers with null values which is..

```
Select 
cust_id As "CustID"
, cust_name_last AS "CustName"
, NVL(to_char(AVG(order_price * quantity), '9999.99'), 'no orders') AS AverageAmntDue
, NVL(to_char(MAX(order_price * quantity), '99999.99'), 'no orders') AS HighestAmntDue
From bk_customers
LEFT JOIN bk_order_headers using (cust_id)
LEFT JOIN bk_order_details using (order_id)
Where extract(year from order_date) = 2014
Group by cust_id, cust_name_last
ORDER by cust_id;
```

I am just super frustrated right now can someone help

Comment: Where TO_CHAR (order_date, 'YYYY’) = 2014

you need to quote 2014 since it's a string

Answer (score 1):

The problem would appear to be the curly closing quote on `'YYYY’`.

I would write the query as:

```
Select cust_id, cust_name_last AS CustName,
       NVL(to_char(AVG(order_price * quantity), '9999.99'), 'no orders') AS AverageAmntDue,
       NVL(to_char(MAX(order_price * quantity), '9999.99'), 'no orders') AS HighestAmntDue
From bk_customers LEFT JOIN
     bk_order_headers
     using (cust_id) LEFT JOIN
     bk_order_details
     using (order_id)
Where extract(year from order_date) = 2014
Group by cust_id, cust_name_last
Order by cust_id;
```

I would also use table aliases on the columns and consider just using `NULL` to mean "no orders", so the
conversion to characters is unnecessary.

Comment: What the task ask for is ...  For each customers we have in the customers table, display the customer id and last name. If 
the customer has any orders last year display the average amount due for those orders and the 
highest amount due for those orders. Display the string ' no orders' if there are no orders. Order 
by the customer id